# Use `:s` in `execute`

Tags: vim

When I use `:s` in command mode, vim will say, for example, "143 substitutions on 14 lines".

Then I put  `:s` in `execute` function.

```
function MoveTrops(oldLocation, newLocation)
    execute 'normal :%s/location=' . a:oldLocation . '$/location=' . a:newLocation . '/g'
endfunction
```

When I call this function, vim will not tell me the number of substitutions.

How do I let vim tell me the number of substitutions as I use `:s` in command mode?

Ideally it'll be better if I can echo how many troops are moved, but the number of substitutions are acceptable.

**One performance concern:**

The function runs on a large file, about 20MB.

Comment: i think you can run `%s/part a/part b/flag` in a script, no?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr but how do I use argument?

Comment: ok. just tried in vi, you can `execute '%s/a/b/g'` in vim but outputs nothing.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr that's why I asked the question.

Comment: You don't need `normal :`, use `execute %s...`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Get rid of the `:norm!`, check your `'report'` setting. Provide a reproducible example.